# Lets encrypt: deleted certificate still valid and running

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt

I've deleted the [www.mydomain.net](http://www.mydomain.net) certificate on my server:

```
sudo certbot delete --cert-name www.mydomain.net
```

everything went ok (apparently) but it turns out that the deleted [www.mydomain.net](http://www.mydomain.net) certificate is still valid in ssl checker and I still have the "name mismatch errors" in my browser when I access my websites.

What can I do ?

Comment: Have you restarted your web server software?

Comment: Also clear cache on your browser, and there may be some ISP caching in the there as well.

Comment: @derpirscher: must be `-connect www.mydomain.net:443` and for OpenSSL below 1.1.1 to a server that uses SNI also need `-servername www.mydomain.net`. However if 'ssl checker' means www.sslchecker.com, which seems likely, that has already provided more info than `s_client` does.

Comment: `delete` just deletes the certificate files on your server. The certificate itself remains valid. If the web server is still running and uses cached/loaded certificate and keys then deleting the certificate has no effect until you restart the server or reload your site config.